# Getting data with Meetups API javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, cors, meetup

I'm trying to use meetups API with an API key, but I'm being blocked by CORS.

I'm using the example meetup gives: `https://api.meetup.com/2/events?key=mykey&group_urlname=ny-tech&sign=true`, replacing the API key with my API key. This example comes from [here.](https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/auth/#keysign)

Here's my code (I took out my key and replaced it with < key>):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="find">find</button>
 <script>
        $("#find").click( function(){
          $.getJSON("https://api.meetup.com/2/events?key=<key>&group_urlname=ny-tech&sign=true", function(data){
            console.log(data);
          });
        });
</script>
```

I'm getting these errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://api.meetup.com/2/events?key=aKey&group_urlname=ny-tech&sign=true'
>   from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. test.html:18
>
> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked
>   cross-origin response
>   https://api.meetup.com/2/events?key=aKey&group_urlname=ny-tech&sign=true
>   with MIME type application/json. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

I'm new to API's and I'm confused about what's going on here. I know that some API requests on meetup's API need OAuth, which I'm still trying to grasp. **However, since this was the example that was used for API keys in the docs as opposed to OAuth, I expected it to work with my API key.** The request works when I simply paste it in the browser but not when I use jQuery to grab it.

There are several places where the documentation talks about CORS:
[Here](https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/#cors) the documentation says

> "you must be using OAuth to benefit from CORS."

And [here](https://secure.meetup.com/meetup_api/oauth_consumers/)

> While we support key-based authentication for first-party
>   applications, we require OAuth for third-party applications that take
>   actions on behalf of other users.

I'm not taking action on behalf of other users. But am I a third party app? What would be a first party app? Under what circumstances would the request I'm making work?

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest blocked by CORS policy` - easiest way to bypass that is by using a *back-end* to load your application. It can be simple as moving your files to an xampp folder or loading it from *NodeJS*.

For your HTTP GET request part of the question, have you [read this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Meetup only allows CORS with requests that are authenticated via OAuth – [reading this issue](https://github.com/meetup/api/issues/130#issuecomment-211538165)

One way is to use [jsonP](https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/#v3_jsonp). After you get your generated API signature URL you can add `?callback=?` as a first parameter and it will work for you.

Here is an example below

```js
$("#find").click(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.meetup.com/2/events?callback=?&offset=0&format=json&limited_events=False&group_urlname=ny-tech&page=200&fields=&order=time&desc=false&status=upcoming&sig_id=SIGID&sig=SIG", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    console.log("error", textStatus);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="find">find</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried this yet because there's a few things I need before I can apply get the OAuth API signature URL, but I will try it eventually. And thanks for taking the keys off my OP. I deactivated the key after you brought it to my attention.